# Plotting users by recording time (timedelta64 format)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to plot the users by recording time :

```
Users              Time 
M. Johns         -1 days +20:07:00
V. Kovic         -1 days +23:07:00
L. DeRoot        15:07:00
S. Steers        15:07:00
K. Krinic        00:07:00
V. Slieve        00:07:53
```

Time is in timedelta64 format. I'd like to plot on x-axis the users in a chronological order, i.e. by time

```
Users              Date 
M. Johns         -1 days +20:07:00
V. Kovic         -1 days +23:07:00
K. Krinic        00:07:00
V. Slieve        00:07:53
L. DeRoot        15:07:00
S. Steers        15:07:00
```

How can I do that? I've tried as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

    df.sort_values(by='Time')

    plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
    plt.plot( df['Users'],df['Time'])
```

But I am not sure the output is correct. On the y-axis there are values in the range -2 to 6 and I cannot understand how to interpret the chart. Also, how could I let the labels on x-axis not overlap? There are a few users that were recorded on the same time and it would be difficult to read their names. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tried to reproduce with following dataset: `df = pd.DataFrame({"Users":["A","B", "A", "D"], "Time":["15:07:00", "15:07:00", "00:07:00", "00:07:53"]})` and for me the plot seems fine: I have labels on x-axis and time on y-axis. The only changed I made is to add `df=` for `df=df.sort_values(by='Time')` for order of labels on x

Comment: how can I see the recording time? is it on the y-axis? in terms of overlapping, since I have many users on the recorded at the same time, how could I visualise them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IICU:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
#Coerce df.Time to datetime
df['Time']=pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'], unit='m')

#Convert negative timedelta to hours or minutes or seconds 
df['Time'] = df['Time'] / np.timedelta64(1, 's') # 'h'/'m'
#if wanted as integer
#df['Time'] =(df['Time'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')).astype(int) 

# Plot
df.sort_values(by='Time', inplace=True)#df.sort_values(by='Time')

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot( df['Users'],df['Time'])
plt.ylabel('Time (s)')
plt.xlabel('Name')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @wwnde. how can I see the recording time? is it on the y-axis? in terms of overlapping, since I have many users on the recorded at the same time, how could I visualise them?

Comment: I just noticed that on the x-axis, the users are not sorted chronologically. I should have Johns, Kovic, Krinic, Slieve, DeRoot, Steers.

Comment: use df.sort_values(by='Time', inplace=True). When inplace=False which is the default, it sorts but does not save the sorted.

Comment: Happy I could help